# How to return a string expression based on two integer columns in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement

I would like to:

```
SELECT  column1,  
        column2,
        column1-column2 as diff,
        (
            IF      column1 > column2 THEN 'ok'
            ELSE    'ko'
            END IF
        ) AS check
FROM    table;
```

If it is not correct, should I be using `DECODE`?

Comment: Are you looking for the [CASE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm) statement?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    column1,
    column2,
    column1-column2 as diff,
    CASE WHEN column1>column2 THEN 'ok'
    ELSE 'ko'
    END as check
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

for example:

select 
column1,
column2, 
(column1- column2) as diff,
case 
when column1 > column2 then 
'ok'
else 
'not ok'
end 
as check